# Cassandra Partition Key with Millions of Rows

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I am trying to build a table that will allow me to do a query on a particular column.  The problem is i need to ensure uniqueness while at the same do this without using a performance hindering method such as ALLOW FILTERING or creating a secondary index since this involves 10's of millions of objects.
I've played with different partition, composite and clustering setups but couldn't seem to get anything to work because of the restriction requirements in the select statements.  How would I know the ID of 10's of millions of records in order to formulate a select statement?

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id int,
    myvalue int,
    mytest txt,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

But the problem is there are 10's of millions of rows that have the same "myvalue" and I need to query a range such as:

```
SELECT mytext FROM test WHERE myvalue > 10 AND myvalue < 20;
```

Comment: If `ID` is unique then a partition key of `ID` + `MYVALUE` would also be unique. That would allow you to query on `ID` and `MYVALUE`.

Comment: You won't be able to do this without a secondary index. This is the limitation of a column oriented database.

Comment: This problem will most likely be solved by changing the data model. If you have tens of millions of records for each id does it make sense to store them in separate keyspaces? The other option is to create a "bucket" column. This is a column with an arbitrary value that will make this type of query easier.